# Issue with @OneToOne unidirectional relationship and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, quarkus

I'm developing a simple application for my database with Quarkus and Hibernate as ORM.

I want to be able to register Users and associate individual UserProfiles with them.

Currently, this is how I've set up the tables in ***PostgreSQL 14***:

```
hibernate=# \d user;
 id           | character varying(36)  |           | not null | 
 created_at   | bigint                 |           | not null | 
 email        | character varying(255) |           | not null | 
 handler      | character varying(36)  |           | not null | 
 locked       | boolean                |           | not null | 
 password     | character varying(255) |           | not null | 
 updated_at   | bigint                 |           | not null | 
 verified     | boolean                |           | not null | 
 account_type | integer                |           |          |
```

```
hibernate=# \d user_profile;
 id         | integer                |           | not null | 
 birth_date | date                   |           |          | 
 created_at | bigint                 |           | not null | 
 first_name | character varying(255) |           | not null | 
 last_name  | character varying(255) |           | not null | 
 telephone  | character varying(255) |           |          | 
 updated_at | bigint                 |           | not null | 
 user_id    | character varying(36)  |           | not null |
```

with `user_id` being the FK for `user.id`.

I've set up my entities like this

```java
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "`user`")
public class User extends PanacheEntityBase {
    
    @Id 
    @Column(name = "`id`", length = 36, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(
        name = "UUID",
        strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
    )
    private String id;
    
    @Column(name = "handler", length = 36, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String handler;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "account_type", nullable = false)
    private Integer accountType;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private Set<Role> roles;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")
    private UserProfile profile;

    @Column(name = "locked", nullable = false)
    private boolean locked = false;

    @Column(name = "verified", nullable = false)
    private boolean verified = false;

    @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false)
    private long createdAt;

    @Column(name = "updated_at", nullable = false)
    private long updatedAt;
}
```

```java
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_profile")
public class UserProfile extends PanacheEntityBase {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "`id`", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Integer id = 1;

    @Column(name = "user_id", length = 36, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String userId;

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="birth_date")
    private LocalDate birthDate;

    @Column(name = "telephone")
    private String telephone;

    @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false)
    private long createdAt;

    @Column(name = "updated_at", nullable = false)
    private long updatedAt;
}
```

Since I'm expecting to receive a `UserDTO` from a **REST** endpoint with a similar structure:

```
{
  "email": "string@email.test",
  "password": "string",
  "handler": "oXaTxETbXyZUCGTd5D2oG77At0B7JPh",
  "roles": [
    "SUPPLIER"
  ],
  "accountType": "PHYSICAL",
  "profile": {
    "firstName": "string",
    "lastName": "string",
    "telephone": "+(535071 778954450",
    "birthDate": "2022-03-10",
    "createdAt": 0,
    "updatedAt": 0
  },
  "addresses": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "state": "z",
      "country": "D",
      "region": "$",
      "province": ";",
      "city": "|",
      "address": "g",
      "postcode": "5",
      "street": "R",
      "suffix": "V",
      "vatNumber": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

what I do is map the UserDTO to a User entity using MapStruct, so I have something like

```java
User user = userMapper.toUser(userDTO);
userRepository.persistAndFlush(user);
```

However, I keep on getting this error:

> An exception occurred! : javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.entities.UserProfile

***How could I fix this issue?***

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")
private UserProfile profile;
```

Instead of `CascadeType.ALL`.

If the cascade type is set to **PERSIST** or **ALL**, Hibernate will try to propagate the persist operation on the detached associated field.

When you persist a `User` entity with one of these cascading types, Hibernate will persist the associated detached `UserProfile`, which will lead to `PersistentObjectException`.

Comment: But I want to persist the UserProfile together with User entity

Comment: @hubfix could you try if this approach will work? It will take a lot of time to create some demos and try this approach by myself.